# Emacs: how to replace a string using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, emacs, replace

suppose i have the following in a text file (or dired buffer) open in emacs:
file_01.txt
file_02.txt
...
file_99.txt

I want to query-replace or replace the files to
01_file.txt, etc.

I want to use query-replace-regexp or replace-regexp, but don't know what to put in.  The search part i put in "file_..", but the ".." are read as periods in the replacement string.  I'm beginning to learn regexp and don't know how to do this.  Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`M-x replace-regexp` invokes the function to replace with regular expressions.

For *Replace regexp* enter: `\(file\)_\([0-9]+\)`

This will create two groups, one that matches the 'file' part, and one that matches the number. The braces `\( ... \)` are necessary to make the match available later in the replacement string.

For *Replace with* enter: `\2_\1`

This inserts the second match from the search string (the numeric part), adds the _ (underscore) and then adds the first match from the search string (the 'file').

For more information on Emacs' regular expressions, see [Regexp Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) and [Regexp Replace](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html).

Once you have mastered the regexp basics you might want to check out the Emacs [ReBuilder](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReBuilder) tool with `M-x re-builder`, which lets you build regexes interactively.